# Telerik MVC WIndow Control - no popup shows up when button clicked second time

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have a page where I am using Telerik window to open a page using ajaxRequest. It work beautifully. However next time when I hit that button, it just doesn't do anything. Below is the code snippet:
var url = "/workbench/createscenario?opportunityid=" + opportunityid + "&customerid=" + customerid
        var window = $("#wndNewScenario").data("tWindow");
        window.ajaxRequest(url);
        window.center();
        window.open();

I even tried with full client side script as below:

```
    var url = "/workbench/createscenario?opportunityid=" + opportunityid + "&customerid=" + customerid;

    var windowElement = $.telerik.window.create({
        title: "Form",
        html: '',
        contentUrl: url,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        onClose: function (e) {
            alert("destroying");
            e.preventDefault();
            windowElement.destroy();

        },
        onRefresh: function (e) {
            windowElement.center();
        }

    }).data('tWindow');

    windowElement.center().open();
```

Any help would be much appreciated ....I really don't want to try out another popup

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the inner HTML on close the window. Like this:

```
onClose: function () {
                    myClass.myWindow = undefined;
                    if ($("#mainDiv") != undefined)
                        $("#mainDiv").remove();
                }
```

Where "myWindow" is the telerik window and "mainDiv" is the div that contais all elements created in your window.

Answer (score 0):

change the order of statement of onclose event and set the variable to null to completely destroy the window

> var windowElement = $.telerik.window.create({
>
> ```
>     title: "Form",
>     html: '',
>     contentUrl: url,
>     modal: true,
>     resizable: true,
>     draggable: true,
>     onClose: function (e) {
>         windowElement.destroy();
>         wndSendEmail = null;
>         e.preventDefault();**
>     },
>     onRefresh: function (e) {
>         windowElement.center();
>     }
>
> }).data('tWindow').center().open();
> ```